# Android facebook tutorial - after login fragment not displaying

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, facebook-android-sdk

I have followed the Facebook android tutorial as far as I can tell line for line for Login authentication. however, I am having issues. When I hav elogge din my "you are now logged in" fragment is never show. I believe this  to be with the showFragment method. please find it below:

```
private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        if (i == fragmentIndex) {
            transaction.show(fragments[i]);
        } else {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
    }
    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}
```

when putting a sys.out in it, fragmentIndex is also 0, and therefore my else fragment is never displayed. Is there something obvious I am missing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please find the rest of the class and the XML just incase:

```
package com.example.social;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;



public class DashBoard extends FragmentActivity {

private static final int SPLASH = 0;
private static final int SELECTION = 1;
private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = SELECTION + 1;
private boolean isResumed = false;

private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragments[SPLASH] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.splashFragment);
    fragments[SELECTION] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.selectionFragment);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}

private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        if (i == fragmentIndex) {
            transaction.show(fragments[i]);
        } else {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
    }
    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void facebookIntent(MenuItem item) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Facebook.class));

}

public void twitterIntent(MenuItem item) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Twitter.class));

}

public void dashboardIntent(MenuItem item) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, DashBoard.class));

}

public void redditIntent(MenuItem item) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Reddit.class));

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isResumed = true;
    uiHelper.onResume();

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
    isResumed = false;
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception exception) {
    // Only make changes if the activity is visible
    if (isResumed) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        // Get the number of entries in the back stack
        int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        // Clear the back stack
        for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
            manager.popBackStack();
        }
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            // If the session state is open:
            // Show the authenticated fragment
            showFragment(SELECTION, false);
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            // If the session state is closed:
            // Show the login fragment
            showFragment(SPLASH, false);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        // if the session is already open,
        // try to show the selection fragment
        showFragment(SELECTION, false);
    } else {
        // otherwise present the splash screen
        // and ask the person to login.
        showFragment(SPLASH, false);
    }
}

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

}

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DashBoard" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/selectionFragment"
        android:name="com.example.social.SelectionFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
        android:name="com.example.social.SplashFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Anybody have any idea? Getting stressed out about it, been stuck for a week or so now. Thanks guys.

Comment: Another bump - pulled my hair out and started again only to run into the same issue.

Comment: This seems to be an unregular problem as I can't find an answer else where and this isn't getting an answer. It almost certainly something I have done wrong so I really would apperiicate any feedback at all.

Comment: seems to be a lost cause :(

Comment: Final atttempt at a bump.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is old, and I hope you have solved the issue. For anyone else facing this problem, ensure that  you have created a facebook app and have enabled native login (which will ask for application package, login class and keyhash. Refer to Section#4 of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/